# VScrollbar CSS for Scroller component in flex

Tags: css, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

Is there a way to customize the look of vertical scroll bar in the Scroller component in Flex? I am able to use CSS to customize the look of Vscrollbar component but I don't see the same option for Scroller component. For example, cornerRadius, fillAlphas isn't available in Scroller component. How can I set these option in Scroller component.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you can't use CSS. In FlashBuilder, you create a new `MXML Skin` and set a host component of `Scroller` and make sure you make it a copy of `spark.skins.spark.ScrollerSkin`. Then you just modify that skin to your heart's content. Not quite as easy as CSS, but it is much more powerful and you can do much, much more. I'm not sure if or how you do it in Flash CS or FlashDevelop, but it is fairly easy in FlashBuilder (and is the proper way to skin all Flex components)

Comment: agree with @Apocalyptic0n3. skin is the best and and more powerful then css. you can change a complete look of any component for which we can define skin. adobe flex has this feature just for user experience.